# Use recoginsed data for replacing

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have column of dates in my Notepad++:

```
2017-06-12
2017-06-13
2017-06-14
2017-06-15
2017-06-16
2017-06-17
2017-06-18
2017-06-19
2017-06-20
2017-06-20
2017-06-21
2017-06-22
2017-06-23
2017-06-24
2017-06-25
2017-06-26
2017-06-27
2017-06-28
2017-06-29
2017-06-30
2017-07-01
2017-07-02
2017-07-03
2017-07-04
2017-07-05
2017-07-06
2017-07-07
2017-07-08
2017-07-09
2017-07-10
```

I need it to cut in weeks by placing `\r\n` after each week like :

```
2017-06-12
2017-06-13
2017-06-14
2017-06-15
2017-06-16
2017-06-17
2017-06-18

2017-06-19
2017-06-20
2017-06-20
2017-06-21
2017-06-22
2017-06-23
2017-06-24
2017-06-25

2017-06-26
2017-06-27
2017-06-28
2017-06-29
2017-06-30
2017-07-01
2017-07-02

2017-07-03
2017-07-04
2017-07-05
2017-07-06
2017-07-07
2017-07-08
2017-07-09

2017-07-10
```

I do replace by using RegEx. I find 7 days:

```
\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\r\n\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\r\n\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\r\n\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\r\n\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\r\n\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\r\n\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\r\n
```

And now I would like to add `\r\n`

But how to use selected data for replace with itself plus `\r\n` ?

Comment: How do you know that a date is sunday?

Comment: The complete solution looks to be a two step one: remove duplicate lines, and then add the linebreaks after each 7th date.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the first date is monday, you could that:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d\R){7}`
- Replace with: `$0\r\n`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Comment: This works fine, but I omit ?: since I don't know what does it means. What ?: is used for?

Comment: @vico Does it handle the `2017-06-20` lines correct?

Comment: @vico: `(?:  )` is called non capture group, it is much more efficient than a capture group.

Answer (score 0):

In your example input there are some lines doubled. e.g. the `2017-06-20`. In your example output this line is also doubled and the *week-block* consists of **eight lines**. **Seven unique** lines and **one doubled** line for `2017-06-20`. I assume that all lines in the input are sorted, thus non unique lines are behind each other. Additionally I assume that the first line marks the first day of a week.

Do a regular expression find/replace like this:

- Open Replace Dialog
- **Find What:** `(((.*\R)\3*){7})`
- **Replace With:** `\1\r\n`
- Check **regular expression**, do not check **. matches newline**
- Click Replace or Replace All

**Explanation**

Lets explain `(((.*\R)\3*){7})` from the inside out, starting at the third inner group: in the following `x,y` are regex-parts and do not mean literal characters.

- `(.*\R)` the third group is just one line from start to end
- `(y\3*)` we look for a `y` followed by an optional part that is captured in the third braces group, here it means a `y` followed by an optional number of repetitions of `y`, here `y` is the third group referenced by `\3`; this deals with the `2017-06-20` case
- `(x{7})` we match seven repetions of `x`, which means here  seven unique rows wich can have repetitions in the block, so 8 line with one line doubled is ok

Comment: This method nice, but becouse of unknown reason I have got 8 items in first set while others are 7.

Comment: It corrects 2017-06-20 , but leaves 2017-11-05. Why?

Comment: What means \1 in replace section?

Comment: The RE captures in `\1` whatever is matched by the first `( ... )`. Here it is  the whole mached text. See for more infos: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/4086774